# How would MACUSA prevent wizards from marrying muggles?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles, fantastic-beasts, marriage

I'm interested in this quote from the film *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* by Newt:

> I do know a few things, actually. I know you have rather backwards laws about relations with non-magic people. That you're not meant to befriend them, that you can't marry them, which seems mildly absurd to me.

So how exactly would they control it? A wizard or a witch is marrying a Muggle and suddenly MACUSA burst into the wedding ceremony and say "No, no, it's forbidden"?

Comment: I'd bet Galleons against Sickles that there are a disproportionately high number of mixed couples in Canada and Mexico as a result of this law.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Through the enforcement of **[Rappaport's Law](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/rappaports-law-en)**

> Rappaport’s Law enforced strict segregation between the No-Maj and wizarding communities. Wizards were no longer allowed to befriend or marry No-Majs. **Penalties for fraternising with No-Majs were harsh.** Communication with No-Majs was limited to that necessary to perform daily activities.
>
> Rappaport’s Law further entrenched the major cultural difference between the American wizarding community and that of Europe. In the Old World, there had always been a degree of covert cooperation and communication between No-Maj governments and their magical counterparts. In America, MACUSA acted totally independently of the No-Maj government. In Europe, witches and wizards married and were friends with No-Majs; in America, **No-Majs were increasingly regarded as the enemy**. In short, Rappaport’s Law drove the American wizarding community, already dealing with an unusually suspicious No-Maj population, still deeper underground.

Much like any <s>Muggle</s> No Maj law, they are hoping the law itself will prevent most witches and wizards from breaking it. Considering the wizarding population really isn't that large (as a percentage of the total population), it is probably not that difficult for American Aurors to perform random inspections.

Would this prevent *all* marriages between No-Majs and Wizards? Probably not, but those that broke the law would have to live in seclusion and in fear that they would be discovered.

Then if discovered, the witch or wizard would be arrested and the No-Maj would be Oblivatiated as was required by International Confederation of Wizards of any No-Maj/Muggle exposed to the Wizarding World.

> As President Rappaport was forced to tell the International Confederation of Wizards at a public inquiry, she could not be sure that every last person privy to Dorcus’s information had been Obliviated. The leak had been so serious that the after-effects would be felt for many years.

Comment: So what would they do if they discovered? Force the couple to divorce?

Comment: @ElisaElisija See edit to address this.

Comment: Prison for the wizard, obliviation for the muggle.

Comment: What if they want to live as Muggles entirely? Can you renounce MACUSA citizenship, as it were?

Answer (score 2):

## There’s a department in MACUSA handling No-Maj fraternization.

One of the departments of MACUSA deals with No-Maj fraternization. They’re likely responsible for preventing wizards from interacting with No-Mags more than is strictly necessary, so they’d also be responsible for preventing wizards from marrying them.

> Rappaport’s Law was still in operation in the 1920s and several offices in MACUSA had no counterpart in the Ministry of Magic; for example, a sub-division dealing with No-Maj Fraternisation and an office issuing and verifying wand permits, which everyone, citizen and visitor, was supposed to carry within the States. 
> <sub><sup>*[- The Magical Congress of the United States of America (MACUSA) (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa)*</sup></sub>

*How* exactly they make sure no wizard marries a No-maj is less clear. MACUSA is stricter than the Ministry, but it’s not mentioned if they have any special way of finding out about a wizard marrying a No-maj.